# Need to remove duplicates in my query oracle r12

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle databases.
I am currently working on query to find the monthy salary of an employee.
I can get to the employee salary. The issue is the query is extremly slow.
I believe this is because it returns duplicates. 
I have found and used the data tracking for the tables I know will have duplicates.
I can not seem to find a way to remove the last set of duplicates.
I think i should use a table I have not used (in my current query) to use that table to remove the duplicates. I appriecte your help and thank you for your time.

```
SELECT  (EEV.SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE)/12 SALARY
FROM apps.PER_JOBS_TL JBT, 
apps.PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F ASF,
apps.PER_PEOPLE_F PER,
apps.PAY_PAYROLL_ACTIONS PPA, 
apps.PAY_ASSIGNMENT_ACTIONS PAA,
PAY_ELEMENT_ENTRY_VALUES_F EEV, 
apps.PAY_ELEMENT_ENTRIES_F EE,
apps.PER_PAY_BASES PPB
----------------------

----------------------
WHERE JBT.JOB_ID(+) = ASF.JOB_ID
and upper(PER.Employee_number) LIKE '%'
AND PER.PERSON_ID = ASF.PERSON_ID
AND PAA.PAYROLL_ACTION_ID = PPA.PAYROLL_ACTION_ID 
AND PPA.ACTION_TYPE IN ('R','Q','P','U','V')
AND PAA.ASSIGNMENT_ID = ASF.ASSIGNMENT_ID

AND PPB.PAY_BASIS_ID        = ASF.PAY_BASIS_ID
AND EEV.INPUT_VALUE_ID+0    = PPB.INPUT_VALUE_ID
AND PPA.DATE_EARNED  BETWEEN ASF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE    AND ASF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND PPA.DATE_EARNED  BETWEEN PER.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE    AND PER.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND PPA.DATE_EARNED  BETWEEN EEV.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE    AND EEV.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND PPA.DATE_EARNED                    BETWEEN EE.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE     AND EE.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE 
AND EE.ASSIGNMENT_ID        = ASF.ASSIGNMENT_ID
AND EE.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID     = EEV.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID


AND ASF.CREATION_DATE  BETWEEN ASF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND ASF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND PPA.EFFECTIVE_DATE BETWEEN '01-dec-2019' AND '31-dec-2019'
```

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92.

Comment: Unfortunatly the design principals of the org I work for, do not allow for the use of modern join syntax.

Comment: Can you provide some information on you schema? Possibly some sample data?

Comment: Can you provide the execution plan? 1) Type: `explain plan for <query>`, then 2) type `select plan_table_output from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'typical'))`.

Comment: @TheImpaler should i paste explain plan or provide a txt?

Comment: @Del I can not provide the scheme as org rules do not allow. sample data "SALARY" "VALUE"
83.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 1.21
83.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 1.21
83.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 1.21
83.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 1.21
83.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 1.21
83.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 1.21

Comment: can PER.Employee_number joined with any column in ASF alias table

Comment: @psaraj12 i joined those two tables using the peron_id. like so     PER.PERSON_ID = ASF.PERSON_ID

Comment: @Musa, Can you try using `distinct` once?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, Distinct works but it does not address the speed requirement. The issue is that when the query is run it will return duplicates then Distinct will then read all the duplicate rows then pick one two display/return. This unfortunatly greatly slows down the query.

Answer (score 0):

By using your query with modern join syntax, it looks something like -

```
SELECT  (EEV.SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE)/12 SALARY
FROM apps.PER_JOBS_TL JBT
LEFT JOIN apps.PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F ASF ON JBT.JOB_ID = ASF.JOB_ID
JOIN apps.PER_PEOPLE_F PER ON PER.PERSON_ID = ASF.PERSON_ID
JOIN apps.PAY_ASSIGNMENT_ACTIONS PAA ON PAA.ASSIGNMENT_ID = ASF.ASSIGNMENT_ID
JOIN apps.PAY_PAYROLL_ACTIONS PPA ON PAA.PAYROLL_ACTION_ID = PPA.PAYROLL_ACTION_ID 
                                 AND PPA.DATE_EARNED BETWEEN ASF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND ASF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
                                 AND PPA.DATE_EARNED BETWEEN PER.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PER.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
JOIN apps.PER_PAY_BASES PPB ON PPB.PAY_BASIS_ID = ASF.PAY_BASIS_ID
JOIN PAY_ELEMENT_ENTRY_VALUES_F EEV ON EEV.INPUT_VALUE_ID+0 = PPB.INPUT_VALUE_ID
                                   AND PPA.DATE_EARNED BETWEEN EEV.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND EEV.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
JOIN apps.PAY_ELEMENT_ENTRIES_F EE ON EE.ASSIGNMENT_ID = ASF.ASSIGNMENT_ID
                                  AND EE.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID = EEV.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID
                                  AND PPA.DATE_EARNED BETWEEN EE.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND EE.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
WHERE UPPER(PER.Employee_number) LIKE '%'
AND PPA.ACTION_TYPE IN ('R','Q','P','U','V')
AND ASF.CREATION_DATE  BETWEEN ASF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND ASF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND PPA.EFFECTIVE_DATE BETWEEN '01-dec-2019' AND '31-dec-2019'
```

I just realized you probably missing join condition for `apps.PAY_ASSIGNMENT_ACTIONS` table. This might be the prime issue for the duplicacy of your result. It is all fine if you have no other join condition for this table.

For speeding up your query, You may try below indices on your tables -

```
apps.PER_JOBS_TL (JOB_ID)              -- Not required if it is primary key
apps.PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F (JOB_ID, PERSON_ID, EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, EFFECTIVE_END_DATE )    -- Not required on primary key columns
apps.PER_PEOPLE_F (PERSON_ID, EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, EFFECTIVE_END_DATE)    -- Not required on primary key columns
apps.PAY_ASSIGNMENT_ACTIONS(ASSIGNMENT_ID)        -- Not required if it is primary key
apps.PAY_PAYROLL_ACTIONS(ACTION_TYPE, EFFECTIVE_DATE, DATE_EARNED)   -- Not required on primary key columns
apps.PER_PAY_BASES(PAY_BASIS_ID, INPUT_VALUE_ID)  -- Not required on primary key columns
PAY_ELEMENT_ENTRY_VALUES_F(INPUT_VALUE_ID, ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID, EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, EFFECTIVE_END_DATE)   -- Not required on primary key columns
apps.PAY_ELEMENT_ENTRIES_F(ASSIGNMENT_ID,ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID, EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,EFFECTIVE_END_DATE)     -- Not required on primary key columns
```

Comment: You must have missed the join on apps.pay_assignment_actions table. It is the join right below the join on the person_id coloumn from both (apps.PAY_PAYROLL_ACTIONS PPA, 
apps.PAY_ASSIGNMENT_ACTIONS PAA) tables.

Answer (score 0):

After searching threw the oracle docs. The answer was in the table pay_payroll_actions. The issues: since oracle writes every change in salary to the pay_payroll_actions table. So if Mr.x got a raise in september, then in the pay_payroll_actions the will be row for Mr.x to indicate a raise and a row for Mr.x to indicate that his salary was paid.

```
Mrx
salary row1
raise row2
```

Therefore using effective date will pull both rows for the date range.
Couple it with creation date then it will pull the information for that specific month.

`PAY_ASSIGNMENT_ACTIONS` has a column name `RUN_TYPE_ID` that runs a dummy run to check all systems work. The Dummy run does not have a org number place in the RUN_TYPE_ID row but the actual run that is run by hr or fiance will have the org number.

The changes are placed like so

```
changes
---------------
```

```
SELECT  
    (EEV.SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE) / 12 SALARY
FROM 
    apps.PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F ASF,
    apps.PER_PEOPLE_F PER,
    apps.PAY_PAYROLL_ACTIONS PPA, 
    apps.PAY_ASSIGNMENT_ACTIONS PAA,
    PAY_ELEMENT_ENTRY_VALUES_F EEV, 
    apps.PAY_ELEMENT_ENTRIES_F EE,
    apps.PER_PAY_BASES PPB
WHERE   
    PER.PERSON_ID = ASF.PERSON_ID
    AND 1 = 1
    AND PAA.PAYROLL_ACTION_ID = PPA.PAYROLL_ACTION_ID 
    AND PPA.ACTION_TYPE IN ('R','Q','P','U','V')
    AND PAA.RUN_TYPE_ID IS NOT NULL
    AND PAA.ASSIGNMENT_ID = ASF.ASSIGNMENT_ID
    AND PPB.PAY_BASIS_ID = ASF.PAY_BASIS_ID
    AND EEV.INPUT_VALUE_ID + 0 = PPB.INPUT_VALUE_ID
    AND PPA.DATE_EARNED BETWEEN ASF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND ASF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
    AND PPA.DATE_EARNED BETWEEN PER.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PER.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
    AND PPA.DATE_EARNED BETWEEN EEV.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND EEV.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
    AND PPA.DATE_EARNED BETWEEN EE.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND EE.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE 
    AND EE.ASSIGNMENT_ID = ASF.ASSIGNMENT_ID
    AND EE.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID = EEV.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID
    AND ASF.CREATION_DATE BETWEEN ASF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND ASF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
    AND PPA.EFFECTIVE_DATE BETWEEN '01-DEC-2019' AND '31-DEC-2019'
    AND PPA.CREATION_DATE  BETWEEN '01-DEC-2019' AND '31-DEC-2019'
```